# Magento2.3.2: How to redirect customer to login page if not logged in before checkout?

Tags: redirect, magento2.3.2

How to redirect the customer to the signin/signup page if not logged in before proceeding to checkout?

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento has an option for logged in based checkout

> Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout

In **Checkout Options** you need to select **Allow Guest Checkout** to **"No"**

This will show a login popup on cart page if the customer is not logged in. It is better than redirecting the user to the login page.

## Edit

If you still want to redirect the user to login page before checkout
Goto

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml
```

Then in the top of the file use this:

```
    //Redirect to login page if customer is not logged in
    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Let me update my answer then

Comment: Please checkout updated answer

Comment: I don't know exactly the path for checkout controller, let me search on google, will share if I get anything

Comment: I have edited your answer without your permission. dont mind

Comment: That's ok, it would help others in future :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to add top links signin when user clicked on checkout instead of login/signup popup ?

Comment: BIG warning : this is not a good practice to put logic in phtml and also it is not an accurate place to manage the redirect : see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/364594/6572 it provides correct implementation for same need